# How do I customize the display of a column in a SharePoint 2007 custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, list, bdc

I create a BDC entry for a web service that exposes a catalog of publications.
Each publication has a collection of authors.
When I display the data in Bussiness Data List the column "Authors" displays "BDC.Authors[]".

Ho do I get Sharepoint 2007 to display the last names, seperated by a ","?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting a similar error message once and found out the reason was something regarding the fact that the data I was returning to the BDC was unserializable. I had to fix my web service to return some serializable data (I think String[] is what I used), and it was fine.

Not exactly the same, but maybe it can get you on the right path.

Comment: Your correct just got the sdame answer from a collegae. I fixed it  by letting the service return concatination of the Authors column value. Thanks anyway. Thought I was the only one with the problem